# Live video conferences on demand

Tags: video

We want to be able to give expert, technical advice to users on demand.

They will click a button on a site (perhaps in an SFDC Community, perhaps not). This creates a case in SFDC, an activity, workflow assigns this task to an expert who will then go online to a video conference with the client.

In the mean time the client has gone into a virtual waiting room dedicated to them, will be able to see the average wait time and anticipated length of call (depending on the question that they asked originally) and will be able to view the content from the expert when they start the call.

The medium may be smart device or computer. They will have to be able to view the video. It is considered unlikely that they will have an app installed that will help with this.

I have been looking at video conferencing apps and have found a few but every one I find has issues, according to the reviews.

The video should be saved and a link to the stored video will be sent to the client.

Questions:

- Have you done anything like this inside Salesforce?
- Do you have any pointers?
- What am I missing in my search?

Comment: Not sure how good a fit it is but have you looked at SOS: http://www.salesforce.com/uk/service-cloud/features/sos/ ?

Comment: Yes - it seems tied to the mobile app experience. Current thinking is that clients are as likely to be on a laptop / desktop as on mobile.

Comment: SFDC not a great choice to save the Videos within the org as that can cost $$$

Comment: Yes - the package used will have to be able to store the videos on a server of our choosing to comply with various legal issues.